# Agent application for FastPath(openfire)

Tags: javascript, openfire, strophe

I am writing an application for agent to make it able to accept/reject chat request and could chat as well with the customers. For work-group I am using Open-fire's Fast-path plugin.
Up-to now I am able to log in to the server as well as could set my status to work-group using strohpe.js well it was a tough task too. I can too accept the chat request distributed by Fast-path to agents but I don't know what to do next. how could i send messages back to work-group so that I will be transferred to customer who requested.
Thanks

Comment: Why not to use Spark for agents?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to implement your own agent app (rather than using Spark for example), you need to follow the [XEP-0142: Workgroup Queues](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0142.html) protocol.

> how could i send messages back to work-group so that I will be
>   transferred to customer who requested.

Well if I understood it correctly, you already sent an agent-offer-accept stanza, then next the server should send a invitation to the agent.

To see how the protocol works I suggest you first to use Spark (with FastPath enabled) then debug the stanzas both on openfire and spark side.

Enable debugging on openfire server:
*Server > Server Settings > Message Audit Policy*

Enable debugging on spark client:
[Uses Spark client to view the XMPP stanzas](http://blog.konca.com/2014/04/12/view-and-send-xmpp-stanzas-by-spark/)

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply but after digging around the internet I got a plugin at: http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/openfire/trunk/src/plugins/jitsivideobridge/src/candy/plugins/fastpath/candy.js?r=13858

It helped me a lot to write agent application for OpenFire's Fastpath.
In addition I had no any idea that we can also debug spark xmpp stanzas thats cool feature..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

once user is sending offer to agents, fastpath creates a multiuser chat room in a workgroup queue. You have to join that MUC room and send messages. Make sure you have queues under you workgroups in Openfire server and have appropriate settings to serve customers.